# IOS: Selecting UICollectionView Cell by Long Press

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I'm using `UICollectionView` to generate a image gallery.I used `UIImage` inside the `UICollectionView` Cell to load the images.I need to select `UICollectionView` Cell by Long Press (not by single tap).

```
- (IBAction)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer
{

    UICollectionViewCell *cell=(UICollectionViewCell *)[gestureRecognizer view];
    int index=cell.tag;

    OverlayImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, cell.frame.size.width,     cell.frame.size.height)];
    OverlayImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Overlay@2x.png"];
    [cell addSubview:OverlayImage];

}
```

Comment: You can use `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Swift 4

updated answer of [it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18848817/5790492)

```
{
    let longPressGR = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleLongPress(longPressGR:)))
    longPressGR.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    longPressGR.delaysTouchesBegan = true
    self.collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressGR)
}

@objc
func handleLongPress(longPressGR: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if longPressGR.state != .ended {
        return
    }
    
    let point = longPressGR.location(in: self.collectionView)
    let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point)
    
    if let indexPath = indexPath {
        var cell = self.collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
        print(indexPath.row)
    } else {
        print("Could not find index path")
    }
}
```

Comment: what's mean : "if let indexPath = indexPath {"

Comment: It unwraps the indexPath, which is `self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: point)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LongPressGesture`

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longpressGesture = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressHandler:)];
    longpressGesture.minimumPressDuration = 5;
    [longpressGesture setDelegate:self];
    [self.yourImage addGestureRecognizer:longpressGesture];


    - (void)longPressHandler:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
        NSLog(@"longPressHandler");
        UIImageView *tempImage=(UIImageView*)[gestureRecognizer view];
    }
```