# ios 8 custom keyboard hold button to delete?

Tags: ios, keyboard, ios8, ios-app-extension, custom-keyboard

I am currently building a custom keyboard and I am almost done. One problem that I have is with the delete button. When the user taps the delete button, it does what it should do and deletes the previous text entry. However when the user holds the button down, nothing happens. How do I make it so that when the user holds down the delete button, the keyboard continuously deletes like in the standard ios keyboard? This is my current code:

## pragma mark Keyboards

```
- (void)addGesturesToKeyboard{
[self.keyboard.deleteKey addTarget:self action:@selector(pressDeleteKey)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and:

```
-(void)pressDeleteKey{
[self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a counter as soon as the screen is touched, such as 2-5 seconds.
The situation known as Long press gesture, and here is the link to the simliar questions.

[Long press gesture on UICollectionViewCell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18848725/long-press-gesture-on-uicollectionviewcell)

Comment: It is a best practice to include all the details in the answer. If you just want to link that's more of a comment.

Comment: If there is a answer there, why should I answer again? And the I could not beat the guy since the link is very detailed.

Comment: If you think the question is the same it is a duplicate. If you're going to "answer" by showing someone elses solution you should comment. If you have a solution that you're providing yourself you should write all the details in the answer.

Comment: @LuoSen if the linked answer gets deleted, your answer will be void too

Comment: This does not fully answer the question. It does not explain how to do repeated deletion.

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3** Use *"allowableMovement"* property

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let longPress = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(KeyboardViewController.handleLongPress(_:)))
    longPress.minimumPressDuration = 0.5
    longPress.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
    longPress.allowableMovement = 0.1
    buttonDelete.addGestureRecognizer(longPress)
}

func handleLongPress(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do this by managing button’s events like touchdown, touchupinside and touchoutside.

When button press at that time start timer with delay of 0.2 seconds and delete last characters from textDocumentProxy until button’s touchup method will fire and after that you just need to invalidate timer.

```
[self.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTocuhDown:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
[self.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.btnDelete addTarget:self action:@selector(btnTouchUp:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpOutside];
```

-(void) btnTocuhDown

```
    NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2  target:self selector:@selector(kpTimerMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

self.kpTimer = timer;
__weak typeof(self)weakSelf = self;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    if (timer == self.kpTimer) {
        [weakSelf.kpTimer fire];
    }
});
```

-(void)kpTimerMethod:(NSTimer *)timer

```
if (self.btnDelete.highlighted)
{
    [self deleteLastCharacter];
}
else
{
    [timer invalidate];
    self.kpTimer = nil;
}
```

-(void)deleteLastCharacter

```
NSString *strInput = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput;

if (strInput.length > 1)
    NSString *coupleOfLastCharacters = [strInput substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(strInput.length-2, 2)];
    if( [@"yo" caseInsensitiveCompare:coupleOfLastCharacters] == NSOrderedSame ) {
        [self.textDocumentProxy deleteLastCharacter];
    }
}
[self.textDocumentProxy deleteLastCharacter];
```

-(void) btnTouchUp

```
[self.kpTimer invalidate];
self.kpTimer = nil;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)addGesturesToKeyboard{

 UILongPressGestureRecognizer *ges = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPress:)];
    ges.minimumPressDuration = 0.1;
    ges.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
    ges.delegate = self;
    [self.mykeyboard.deleteKey addGestureRecognizer:ges];
}

- (void)longPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gesture {


        [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
```