# Clear text in text field long press clear button iphone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am currently building a custom keyboard and I am almost done. One problem that I have is with the delete button. When the user taps the delete button, it does what it should do and deletes the previous text entry. However when the user holds the button down, nothing happens. How do I make it so that when the user holds down the delete button, the keyboard continuously deletes like in the standard ios keyboard?

Comment: once have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6179347/uibutton-long-press-event

Comment: @anil Do you got any solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: we have just clear the all text on  long press @PavanMore

Comment: @anil How ? I just tried making long press and deleting all text on long press, Its working for me:  /** while ([self.textDocumentProxy hasText]) {
           [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward]; }  **/
Is their any other way to clear ?

Comment: exactly i have delete it on long press as u said no any other solution of it

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/customkey-keyboard/id929596834 this my app link u can check it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ios 8 custom keyboard hold button to delete?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633189/ios-8-custom-keyboard-hold-button-to-delete)

Answer (score 0):

You should also register for the action `UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat`  for delete button by below way.

```
[deleteButton addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteCharacter:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDownRepeat];
```