# Add Pan Gesture to UICollectionView Cell - IOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uipangesturerecognizer

I have an UICollectionView and I want to add pan gesture to its Cells/Items. When I add the gesture in usual way UICollectionView is not getting scrolled.

This is how I add the gesture

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:UICollectionViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(CaptureViewController.pagesCollectionViewItemPanEvent(_:)))
    cell.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    return cell;
}
```

Is there something wrong here? Can someone please tell me a way to get my work done. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: check this answer i hope it help you :) [Swift gesture](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18848817/6628878)

Comment: Try extending your collection view object, from there implement touchesbegan touch events method. And then handle your pan event, and then implement [super touchevents] method, so that the existing collectionview scroll will not affect.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the gesture to the collection view and not to the cell itself.
Something like...

```
let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "handlePanGesture:")
collectionView.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

func handlePanGesture(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

    let locationInView = gesture.locationInView(collectionView)
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Just a proposal, I didn't test it:**

Create a custom cell:

```
class PanCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.pagesCollectionViewItemPanEvent(_:)))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)
    }
}
```

and you can use the delegation to inform `CaptureViewController`.

Comment: Creating a custom class for cell will solve my problem?? Sorry I din't get this. Can you please explain :)

Comment: Creating a custom cell you can manage the gesture inside the cell, I don't know if is going to fix your problem but I help you to separate the class behaviours and it is a good start point to solve your problem.

Comment: No worries, if my idea will help you mark my question, I would appreciate it, otherwise will try to help you :)

Comment: Okay, sure 